# How to send GET requests with JSON body using requests 2.18?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Is there a way to send json request body in a GET request when using `requests.Session()`? `sessions.get()` does not have data / json argument unlike `post()` and `put()`

requests - 2.18.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sessions.request()` method. This allows you to pass in the method name as a string along with the other parameters.

Example:

```py
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.request(method="GET", url=url, json=json)
```

**Side Note:**
If you inspect the `session.get()` method, you will find that it too internally calls the request() method:

```py
    def get(self, url, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
```